# Monitoring Incoming Scans from a scanner using a custom Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, wia

I need a way to monitor incoming scans from a scanner. I'm using Windows Image Acquisition Library 2.0 to communicate between the scanner and my application. It's working fine for me given that the user scans the flatbed using my application, but what I really want to accomplish is that when the user scans using the button from the scanner itself, it starts up my application and takes the image from there.

Ideally, what I want is a background process just listening to incoming scans. How do I accomplish this using a custom Windows Service? Or is there any alternative way on implementing this?

I've tried taking a look myself on using Windows Services but I'm stuck on what should be on the OnStart() method and I have no idea what helper classes are available for me.

Any help would be much appreciated.